# Fullcalendar dayClick event not firing on certain time slots

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a couple full calendars that I use for various things and recently I discovered that my dayClick event isn't firing on some of my time slots. The calendar has 2 time slots per day, basically morning and evening, and the only ones that don't work are the Saturday Evening, and the last day of the date range's evening slot. The dayClick works just fine on every other time slot. I have searched and searched and couldn't find anything that helped. I also tried removing any of the date ranges and that didn't fix anything. It literally just doesn't fire on any Saturday evening and I cant figure out why. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
 DateTime endDate =startDate.AddDays(7);
 model.ShortStartDate = startDate.ToShortDateString();
 model.ShortEndDate = endDate.ToShortDateString();


@{
  var shortStartDate = Model.ShortStartDate.ToString();
  var shortEndDate = Model.ShortEndDate.ToString();
  var startDate = shortStartDate;
  var endDate = shortEndDate;
}
<script>
  var startDate = @startDate;
var endDate = @endDate;
 var shortStartDate = @shortStartDate;
var shortEndDate = @shortEndDate;
var startoffSet = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var endoffSet = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;


$(document).ready(function () {
    var calendarStartDate = new Date(startDate - startoffSet);
    calendarStartDate.setDate(calendarStartDate.getDate() + 2);
    var calendarEndDate = new Date(endDate - endoffSet);
    calendarEndDate.setDate(calendarEndDate.getDate() + 2);
    $('#scheduleEditCalendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        views: {
            agendaWeek: {
                start: calendarStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1), //new Date(startDate - startoffSet).toISOString().slice(0, -1),
                end: calendarEndDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1) //new Date(endDate - endoffSet).toISOString().slice(0, -1)
            }
        },
        validRange: {
            start: "@shortStartDate",
            end: "@shortEndDate",
        },
        axisFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        allDaySlot: false,
        allDayDefault: false,
        displayEventTime: false,
        eventBackgroundColor: "#98700D",
        visibleRange: {
            start: calendarStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1),
            end: calendarEndDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1)
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {              
                console.log("day clicked", date);
                $("#dateChosenHidden").val(date.format().toString());
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddUserToWalkPartial")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: $('#AddWalkerToScheduleForm').serialize(),
                    modal: true,
                    success: function (partialView) {
                        console.log("Date Chosen: " + $("#dateChosenHidden").val());
                        $('#AddWalkerModalContent').html(partialView);
                        $('#AddWalkerModal').modal({ backdrop: true, toggle: true });
                    }
                });

        },
        eventClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            var today = moment(new Date());
            console.log(view);
            console.log(date.title);
            if (today > checkDateStart && today < checkDateEnd){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("EditUserForWalkPartial")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {eventDate: date.start._i, usersName: date.title, patientId: @Model.Patient.Id},
                    modal: true,
                    success: function (partialView) {
                        $('#AddWalkerModalContent').html(partialView);
                        $('#AddWalkerModal').modal({ backdrop: true, toggle: true });
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        eventSources: [{ events: eventss }],
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            var cellheight = $(element).height();
            $(element).css('height', '15px');
            if (event.type == 'true') {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'green');
            }
            else {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        }
    })
    $('#scheduleEditCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'contentHeight', 'auto');
    $('#scheduleEditCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'minTime', '07:00:00');
    $('#scheduleEditCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'maxTime', '24:00:00');
    $('#scheduleEditCalendar').fullCalendar('option', 'slotDuration', '12:00:00');


});
```

Comment: what values are you using for `@shortStartDate` and `@shortEndDate` please? Apart from that, I'd be able to use your code to make a runnable demo to try and reproduce your issue. Actually I'd also need the values of `startDate`, `endDate`, `startoffSet` and `endoffSet` as well. Thanks.

Comment: Also, any reason you're setting those 4 options (contentHeight, minTime, maxTime, and slotDuration) separately after the main call to create the calendar? They can all be specified in the main options list directly.

Comment: Edited the question to include those values you asked about. As to why i did the minTime, maxTime, etc that way is basically just leftover from a different calendar that I had used and was changing those values depending on other variables and I just didn't change the code back to do it the normal way.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the code doesn't seem to work at all - it falls apart when injecting the data values which would be produced by printing those values from the C# code: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/185/ - notice the "NaN" values, consequent Invalid Date values and then jQuery errors. You can't substract a timezone offset from a date string. Maybe I've reproduced this incorrectly - perhaps you can show me a sample of the values which are actually being injected into your JavaScript by the `@` statements?

Comment: I added some more to the code, guess i didn't think that little bit was needed, my bad. But it definitely runs. I also haven't added the event creation code, since i assume its not needed to debug this, but let me know if you need that too. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/188/ Here this runs and still has the problem I am trying to fix.

Comment: So i figured it out kind of. If you change the minTime to 00:00:00 the click event now works on the calendar. But I don't want the time to display 12am and 12pm. I need it to show different times than that but still only have 1 slot.

Comment: Thanks. that is pretty weird. I would be tempted to submit a bug to fullCalendar. I can't really see that you've done anything wrong.