# Fullcalendar events not rendering where they should

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I had a bug with my dayClick function not firing they way I had some agendaView calendars set up, so i found a way to remove the time slots I didn't want instead of setting the minTime, maxTime, and slotDuration to display the time slots i wanted. By removing the table rows, the events no longer render properly. Is there a way I can change where the events render. Here is a codepen with an example demonstrating my issue. Thanks

```
``https://codepen.io/darkwingduck/pen/JmGwPX
```

Edit to better explain: So I need to have a calendar that shows a week at a time that has two time slots and the first one starting at 7am and the 2nd one at 7pm and a dayClick event for each slot. The problem with setting the minTime to 7am and the duration to 12 causes the Saturday evening dayClick not to work. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Please better describe your issue. Also tell what's your desired output

Comment: Look at my codepen to see the example. I basically want my events to show up where they should. Like a 7am event should show up in the 7am row, not way down below.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant test it right now but if that fixes it I will be super happy. When I get a chance I'll try it out and let you know. thanks

Comment: fullCalendar's HTML is built as a series of tables layered on top of each other and positioned absolutely (you can see this for yourself if you examine the rendered source using your browser's Developer Tools. The events are positioned on the upper grid based on assumptions about where the timeslots have been positioned on the lower grid. If you manually mangle the lower grid then it's inevitable that the events will appear to be in the wrong place. fullCalendar has no knowledge of what you've done to the HTML when rendering the events. Your solution is crude and will never work properly.

Comment: You would be better off getting the bug with the dayClick fixed (as discussed in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608749/fullcalendar-dayclick-event-not-firing-on-certain-time-slots)). fullCalendar is open-source so of course you always have the option to make a contribution to this yourself to speed up the process. And/or you can manually patch your own version while waiting for it to be fixed in the official release.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I spent some time trying to fix the bug in full calendar but was kind of lost. I reported the bug to them but other than them agreeing that it was a bug I haven't heard anything else. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Another option, depending what you're using the dayClick for, is to see whether the [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callback would meet your needs instead - that's normally the recommended callback to use to allow users to create a new event, for instance.